# NSCoding - saving array to file or nsdefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, nscoding

Afternoon all,

Working on my first iphone app.
I am trying to save an array of an array either to file or nsuserdefaults.
Data is like this...

MainArray (contains 3 below arrays)
  Array1 (contains 3 strings)
  Array2 (contains 3 strings)
  Array3 (contains 3 strings)

So far I've been reading about saving things to nsuserdefaults, and saving to file.  Not sure which is the right way or benefits of either but I start trying saving to file.

below is my custom object to save information.

```
@implementation UserSettingsClass


+ (instancetype)sharedUserData{
static id sharedInstance = nil;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    //sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
});

return sharedInstance;
    }


 -(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
[encoder encodeObject:self.arrayUserSettings forKey:@"someArray"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.userDescription forKey:@"testDesc"];
}


 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
if ((self = [super init])){
    self.userDescription = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"testDesc"];
    self.arrayUserSettings = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someArray"];
}
return self;
}

+(NSString *)filePath{
static NSString *filePath = nil;
if (!filePath){
    filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"];
}
return filePath;
}

+(instancetype)loadInstance{
NSData *decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[UserSettingsClass filePath]];
if (decodedData){
    UserSettingsClass *gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
    return gameData;
}
return [[UserSettingsClass alloc] init];
}


-(void)save{
NSData *encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
[encodedData writeToFile:[UserSettingsClass filePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

and here is the main class where I am trying to use it.

```
    //initialize variables
//_userArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//_userDescription = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testDescription"] init];
//_userLoginID = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testLogin"] init];
//_userPW = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testPassword"] init];
//    [_userArray addObject:[UserSettingsClass sharedUserData].userDescription];
//[_userArray addObject:_userLoginID];

//[[UserSettingsClass sharedUserData].arrayUserSettings addObject:           [UserSettingsClass sharedUserData].userDescription];

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [UserSettingsClass    sharedUserData].arrayUserSettings;

//[_userArray addObject:_userPW];

//save data to shared singleton class
//[[UserSettingsClass sharedUserData].arrayUserSettings addObject:_userArray];

//NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//tempArray = [UserSettingsClass sharedUserData].arrayUserSettings;

//[UserSettingsClass sharedUserData].highScore = 10;
//int i = [UserSettingsClass sharedUserData].highScore;

//[UserSettingsClass sharedUserData].userDescription = @"hello";
NSString *temp2 = [UserSettingsClass sharedUserData].userDescription;
```

I am able to save the single string, but I must be doing something wrong.
The single string I saved was just to see if I can get it working.  My goal is to save the main array to file (or nsuserdefaults), which contain about 3 objects (array)... and each of those arrays contains 3 strings each.

any I doing something blatantly wrong?

Comment: thanks zaph... first question.. why do you say <Shudder> to save to nsuserdefaults... is it bad to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to hard.

If what you want to save is just NSArrays and NSStrings to you do not need so add an NSCoding, these types already conform to NSCoding. Just Archive to a file or "shudder" save to NSUserDefaults "/shudder".

It is really better to create a Data Model class and use NSArchiver to save and restore from a file in the Documents directory.

Comment: why is nsuserdefaults a bad option?  and if I dont need to add nscoding... when is the right time to add it?

Comment: You can but that is rarely a good idea. Note that among other things it is based on string based keys so there is no type checking. It is easily accessed from a connected computer. There is an extra step to know if the item exists, this is a particular problem with BOOLs. It is subject to the "Broken Window" syndrome. Instead just use a Data Model and save it to and restore from a file using NSArchiver. This works well as more items are added to the data model/ A Data Model class can provide capabilities that a `NSUserDefaults` entry can not.

Comment: just still a bit confused... when is adding nscoding a necessity?

Comment: When NSArchiver is going to be used. But note that many Apple classes already conform to NSCoding or NSSecureCoding. Look in the Apple documentation under "Conforms To".

Comment: Apple: The NSUserDefaults class provides a programmatic interface for interacting with the defaults system. The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences. For example, you can allow users to determine what units of measurement your application displays or how often documents are automatically saved. Applications record such preferences by assigning values to a set of parameters. The parameters are referred to as defaults since they’re commonly used to determine an application’s default state at startup or the way it acts by default.

Comment: thanks so much. saving to a file and reading using nskeyedarchiver worked!  thanks!  last random question, I am saving to [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userSettingsData"];.  is there somewhere I can actually look at the folder using like FINDER, or like a windows explorer type feature?